# How to transpose and Pandas DataFrame and name new columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have simple Pandas DataFrame with 3 columns. I am trying to Transpose it into and then rename that new dataframe and I am having bit trouble.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TotalInvoicedPrice': [123],
               'TotalProductCost': [18],
               'ShippingCost': [5]})
```

I tried using

```
df =df.T
```

which transpose the DataFrame into:

```
TotalInvoicedPrice,123
TotalProductCost,18
ShippingCost,5
```

So now i have to add column names to this data frame "Metrics" and "Values"
I tried using
df.columns["Metrics","Values"]
but im getting errors.
What I need to get is DataFrame that looks like:

```
  Metrics            Values
0 TotalInvoicedPrice 123
1 TotalProductCost    18
2 ShippingCost         5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's reset the index then set the column labels

```
df.T.reset_index().set_axis(['Metrics', 'Values'], axis=1)
```

---

```
              Metrics  Values
0  TotalInvoicedPrice     123
1    TotalProductCost      18
2        ShippingCost       5
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can avoid transpose operation (little performance overhead)

```
#YOUR DATAFRAME
df = pd.DataFrame({'TotalInvoicedPrice': [123],
               'TotalProductCost': [18],
               'ShippingCost': [5]})

#FORM THE LISTS FROM YOUR COLUMNS AND FIRST ROW VALUES
l1 = df.columns.values.tolist()
l2 = df.iloc[0].tolist()

#CREATE A DATA FRAME.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1, l2)),columns = ['Metrics', 'Values'])

print(df2)
```